# how to deploy a corrected library

Tags: google-apps-script

I find a bug in a library (release 8) already used by many scripts.
I want these scripts to used the corrected library, but I can't change the library release number in each script.

I'd like replace the code in release 8 by the new code, with the same release number.

Is'it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to update the code of a version and keeping the same version number but you could use the Google Apps Script API to update the version of your library used by your scripts.

Comment: Do you know a way to :

* find all scripts using this library in the organisation ?
* to modfy library version in these scripts with a batch ?